# Can anyone help identify a (presumably) vintage Battaglin bike for my uncle?

Tags: road-bike, vintage

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My uncle fixed a man's shed, and was paid with this bike. He knows the man was quite into cycling before he retired, so we're presuming its quite a good bike, but we can't identify any more than the manufacturer; Battaglin.

We are torn between keeping it and using it, or - if its worth something - selling it on, and buying two cheap run-around bikes.

Does anyone have any tips on where we can look to find the model? Sadly, the bike shop on the sticker closed down some years ago.

Any help you can provide would be hugely appreciated!

Kindly,
R.

Comment: It seems a legit Battaglin frame, assembled in Italy but I am not sure made in Italy. It is a mid-quality bicycle (see the rough brazing) from the 90s. That downtube shape gave a lightweight construction, but it was also very rigid and it gave a rather harsh ride. It was common on other aluminium italian road bikes from the 90s.
Good bike, but harsh ride, I would say "sell". Write to the  manufacturer https://officinabattaglin.com/ , the founder still alive, the company is going strong, they may help you identifying it.

Comment: It is not a new bike, but not really vintage, It would not be Eroica-legal. The shifters in particular are fairly modern.

Comment: @VladimirF what's the Eroica rule? before the 80s? Battaglin started his biccle business in 1982, so it cannot be older than 1982 :) . Anyhow, very similar to this one:
https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/s-anzeige/battaglin-aluminium-rennrad-gelb/1763839357-217-6092
but no name is given

Comment: @EarlGrey can be 80s, but must be downtube shifters and cables heading up from the brake levers. And no no internal cables, I think.

Comment: Interesting combination of Shimano shifters and derailleur and Campagnolo crank. It's anyone's guess how much of it is original. Otherwise, I'd say this bike is as 90s as CD collection of eurodance hits :)

Comment: I just noticed there may be an issue with the brake cable eating into the frame or the brazing, when it comes out of the bottom bracket guides.

Comment: @EarlGrey: It's the FD cable that is eating into the BB. The rear brake cable passes under the top tube.

Comment: BTW its not a "BAT-a-glin" its a "b'-TAAA-glin"  when said.  Feel free to add some italian accent, and even throw in some hand gestures for effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a loverly bike, and would make a great ride.  The exact model doesn't matter much at all, wear and general condition are more important.  Sadly, serial numbers don't really help.

Looks to date from the early 90s, when aluminium was new, and frame tubes were oversized compared to the thin steel tubes that came before.  These frames had a "thickness" that make them look great.  And a horizontal top tube has a visual appeal too.

The yellow colour is hard to keep clean, but it also looks great.

The only things I see "wrong" are that the front Quick Release lever is either loose or at a weird angle, and that's really minor.  The saddle looks to be angled up in the nose and may be uncomfortable.

Given that the bike supply chain is somewhat constrained in many C19-affected parts of the world, you might choose to pass it on, or keep it for yourself and try out this cycling stuff.

In short - its a pretty Italian, I'd totally keep it.

Comment: The saddle is a first generation Selle Italia Flite. It is very comfy when the nose is perfectly horizontal. Another BB cable guide would solve the problem with the FD cable. This one looks like a slightly unsuitable replacement intended for a skinnier BB.

Comment: @Carel is the Selle Italia Flite always coming with titanium rails? 
I have seen many on sale on eBay, in better conditions they still sell for 100 GBP or so.

Comment: @EarlGrey: Most early 'Flite' had Ti rails. I have two of those on two different road-bikes. Later they produced some with Vanadium-steel rails aimed at heavier riders.

Comment: I actually got a reply from Battaglin to give me some information about the bike! The message I received was: "I'm Dario from Officina Battaglin, this is an old Alu model that was made back in '97. It's called Tubone (big tube) and it was an entry level model ." It's good to put a name to a frame!

Comment: @R-bike you should totally add that info as an answer, and then mark it as "accepted"

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go against the grain a bit here, and say that you've got a great example of something from the dark ages of Italian bicycle manufacture. It is an early 90s bike. I know this because the phone number on the shop's sticker starts with an 01, dating it to after BT changed all the area codes.

The welding is dreadful/ugly and while the bike will be quite exciting to ride and is a great colour, they tend to be quite harsh and unforgiving, so you'll know it in your bones after you've been out for a long ride. The aluminium aero fork is completely badass though, really nice, though firm!

Last year (2020) I sold a very similar Coppi that had come from the tip; I valued it at £100 after researching past ebay listings for similar bikes. You can try the same method. The guy that has it now really likes it because it looks cool and it has a famous name on it, but it isn't a valuable bike.

Enjoy it for what it is, a cool looking bike with some Italian flair but missing the craftsmanship associated with the older bikes of the same brand.

---

I'm just going to add that the Coppi Gavia I'm referring to could actually be based on the exact same frameset as the details look pretty much identical.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers/comments! We're definitely not selling the bike, your enthusiasm has got me excited to make some use out of it.